# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation scales image

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIImageView and I am applying a rotation transform using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`. This does not only rotate the image but scales it as well.

What is the correct way to rotate a UIImageView and retain the size/scale of the image?

I tried setting

```
self.image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
self.image.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Rotation transform doesn't scale the image. There must be some other problem with your code. Are you using storyboards to create the `UIImageView`? Try to narrow it by commenting out references to the object or try to create a small sample project reproducing the problem

Comment: I create the UIImageView in code and I apply a transform to it. After reading around here the issue is that the rotated view tries to fit the image into it and stretches it. There are some solutions using IB, but I am doing it in code.

Comment: @Mar0ux - I have just created a basic UIView with a UIImageView rendered in its drawRect method using drawInRect.

Comment: Are you drawing the image yourself using `drawInRect`? If so, you need to apply the transform to the `CGContextRef`. Also, be aware that `UIView`'s `frame` property isn't valid after applying a transform.

Comment: Yes I am drawing them using drawInRect. I pass in the frame which you say is invalid. It renders, just scaled. What frame is it using? I apply the transform to the context. I have 3 images that scale and rotate independently and are stacked on top of one another. I cannot apply the transform to the entire context.

Comment: [Warning: If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/). I think you need to apply transform, draw image, apply reverse transform (or restore state - not sure if transform is part of context state).

Answer (score 0):

try the below method

```
-(UIImage*)rotateImage:(UIImage*)img forAngle:(CGFloat)radian   {

    UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radian);
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
    CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, rotatedSize.width, rotatedSize.height);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, radian);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(-img.size.width, -img.size.height, img.size.width, img.size.height), img.CGImage);
    UIImage *returnImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return returnImg;
}
```

Comment: I cannot do it this way as I render imageview.image into the context with a blend mode and then transform the imageview. Then I call setNeedsDisplay to get the new translate to render.